# Using custom DNS name to point to my EC2 machine using route 53 A record?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a custom domain: `develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in`

i have created a record set with a record of A name type that points to my elastic ip for my ubuntu machine.

Questions :

1. Is being added to the domain name develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in.
2. I have a app running on my server. When i used my elastic ip on address bar all work good i am landing on its index page. But when i used my domain name I am getting `develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in server IP address could not be found`.

Comment: try step which i gave this will help you to understand. @sumanth-shetty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a record setup for that domain, just the root level domain.

I ran a DIG command and here's what it returns

```
id 40482
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
waveaxis.co.in. IN ANY
;ANSWER
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN MX 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN MX 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN MX 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN MX 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN MX 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com ~all"
waveaxis.co.in. 21599 IN SOA ns8351.hostgator.com. root.gator4176.hostgator.com. 2020061700 86400 7200 3600000 86400
waveaxis.co.in. 21599 IN NS ns8351.hostgator.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 21599 IN NS ns8352.hostgator.com.
waveaxis.co.in. 14399 IN A 108.167.143.137
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Either add a wildcard of `*.waveaxis.co.in` or add the absolute domain name.

Comment: This can help you to get idea. upvoting this answer.

Comment: hi @Chris , I have A record set up for the domain develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in. 
while creating A record in route 53 i have used the absolute record (develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in)

Comment: also would like to add develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in is my hosted zone

Comment: @sumanthshetty your name servers are with hostgator. If thats not what you're expecting you'll need to update with Hostgator to use the name  servers in your Route 53 public hosted zone

Comment: @ChrisWilliams apparently i got to know now that .
only domain we have is waveaxis.co.in and we dont even have the subdomain(develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in)for which i created the hosted zone.
the domain is registered with https://www.znetlive.com/ but it is hosted on Hostgator.

what should i do now to have develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in pointing to my ip

Comment: Either in host gators DNS service add the record, or update in host gator to change the nameserver to Route 53s. There are some docs here: https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/how-do-i-change-my-dns-or-name-servers

Comment: @ChrisWilliams . thank you for you being patient with me from yesterday :)
just checking if i got this right.
1 create a hosted zone with waveaxis.co.in
2 replace the NS generated from route 53 with hostgator.
3 created A record with develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in point to the ip of mu ubuntu machine 

Hope i got it right ? and what about SOA which is generated ?

Comment: So update Hostgator name server settings to the 4 name servers in Route 53. Add an A record the to public hosted zone in route 53 to add your subdomain. Leave SOA record

Comment: @ChrisWilliams your a life saver man it worked. thank you so much.
coming back to my part one of my question. 
there is (.) being added at the end of my subdomain name .
it works normally , but wanted to know what does (.) signify ? if it does anything

Comment: The . Is actually the root domain, although traditionally it is not needed visually it is always part of the domain. Here’s some more info https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server :)

Answer (score 1):

Most reason your host is not resolved due to this you are getting error.

Try in your machine :

`sudo /etc/host/` and temporary added

for macOs and ubuntu is same path. Window will have different path.

https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/what-is-the-hosts-file-and-how-to-use-it-#:~:text=The%20hosts%20file%20is%20a,and%20is%20traditionally%20named%20hosts.&text=Windows%20operating%20systems%20contain%20a,resolution%20of%20your%20domain%20name.

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in
```

and save it check whether you are getting website or not.

If this working then your DNS resolve takes times.

`ping develop.yp-uae.waveaxis.co.in` in your terminal once you got ping reply then DNS is resolve for this.